# android keep cpu running at full speed while screen is off

Tags: android, multithreading, service, cpu, power-management

I have created an application that compare the android phone cpu speed by running the same tasks on multiple phones. I noticed that on the HTC ONE X it becomes much slower if I turn off the screen while it does not change when doing the same thing on the other phone. In the program I put the task in a service and running in a separate thread with priority set to be the highest value 10.

I tried to use the partial wake lock to keep the cpu running when screen is off. But it doesn't make any difference in terms of the speed.

I understand that different OS/UI (HTC sense for example) has its own power management strategy. But I am wondering if there is any way to overcome it without rooting your phone, means keep cpu running in 100% clock rate?

Updates: recent experiments show that when screen is off, One X (with ICS) will reduce its cpu frequency and disable the multi-core functionality, the Galaxy Nexus (with ICS) will reduce about 25% performance, Nexus 7 will reduce about 25% performance most of the time (occasionally it can run at the highest speed while screen is off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why the wake lock didn't work?

For Qualcomm devices the hotplugging on and off of CPUs is handled with a program called `mpdecision`. The `mpdecision` file runs in our system as a vendor executable file and what it does is that it controls the governor for cpu. `mpdecision` defines performance of your cpu1, the file gets executed every time your screen goes off, hence cpu1 scripts are useless because the `mpdecision` file overwrites the cpu1 governor settings to `userspace` `ondemand`, `userspace` is the governor when cpu1 is online and `ondemand` is when offline. [Reference](http://www.scottsroms.com/showthread.php?447-CPU1-governor-change-with-MPDECISION-file-script)

2. Is there any thing I can do to keep the CPU not reducing its frequency?

You need to stop `mpdecision`, then you can keep CPU frequency. However, stopping `mpdecision` need root privilege. So I think you can't keep CPU frequency without root privilege.

You can write value to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online` to open or close core of CPU and write value to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed` to set frequency of each core. I tries this method in Nexus 4, and it works fine.

For more details you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25911984/3103844).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But my question is why the wakelock didn't work and without rooting the device, is there any thing I can do to keep the CPU not reducing its frequency?

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful information. I found more descriptions about mpdecision and i'll add them in your answer.