# Locking the CPU on android for app performance testing

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage, android-testing, cpu-speed

I'm trying to test an app's performance on android at different CPU states. So i will like to lock the CPU at say 1000Mhz and take readings and then overload the CPU and take readings. My question is: Is there anyway to lock the CPU and possibly the RAM at certain lock/freeze rates?? Any link to documentations on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: on a device or the emulator?

Comment: Hi..sorry on an actual android device

Comment: You can try my answer, I tried in Nexus 4, and it works fine.

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: yes it did..another thing please, is the anyway to "programatically" load the CPU and make it very busy?

Comment: Just do some calculation. For multi cores, just start multi threads. I think you should ask another question for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps(all steps with root privilege):
1. `stop mpdecision`
2. In `/sys/devices/system/cpu` you can see how many cores in your device, if dual core, you will see `cpu0` and `cpu1` two folders.
3. write `0` or `1` to disable or enable core

```
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online # disable core
echo "1" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online # enable core
```

4. change governor of CPU

```
echo "userspace" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

5. set frequency

```
echo "1000000" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed
```

remember to check `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` to see what frequency you can set in step 5.

For step 4 and 5, you can set frequency through [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhuang.overclocking) app(need root privilege).

For more details, you can see [this](http://bamboopuppy.com/how-to-do-a-cpu-hotplug-in-android/).

Comment: Ok will try that and report back. Also do i send thede commands through adb shell??

Comment: Yes, through `adb shell`, first `adb shell`, then `su`, and follow my steps

Comment: yes this is certainly the correct answer..thank you for the link also..very nice

Comment: can you please edit step 4 of your answer, it should be scaling_governor without an s @PageNotFound